# Is asking for a test API endpoint off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In a question that has since been deleted, a user was asking for a test API endpoint (see screenshots below).

I assumed that this qualifies as asking for a recommendation for an external resource and voted to close the question.

The user felt this was unfair and that the question is valid.

**Should I have retracted my close vote?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: can we have a picture of the entire context?  the post was deleted.

Comment: @snb updated to include shot.

Comment: @snb also added a screenshot of the comments.

Comment: My policy is that most of the time, the person who is downvoting your question knows better. If they don't, they will only make up 0.1% of the downvotes (as the people who don't know better are also on the site less). If you get lots of downvotes - hey, it's an excuse to delete it and get the Peer Pressure badge :D

Comment: I downvoted because there was no apparent own effort and research by the poster

Comment: @PatrickHund no offence :)

Comment: @Solver None taken 

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's off-topic, for exactly the reason you stated:

> *"it is an off-site resource, and asking for recommendations for those are off topic"* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068166/is-there-coinbase-sandbox-test-api#comment83119101_48068166))

So no, don't retract the vote. I've added my own.

The OP calling you a "thug" doesn't mean the OP is right. It just means he doesn't quite understand what qualifies as off-topic on the site, and feels entitled to having the question stay open.

The question is now closed & deleted.

Comment: The OP calling him a "thug" mainly means he does not understand the _Be nice_ policy…

Comment: That too. I was referring to the sense of entitlement that must accompany a comment like that ;-)

Comment: -1; leaving aside the user's behaviour (the insults were nuked before I arrived), I'm with them as far as topicality goes. I don't think asking about the existence of endpoints within a specific API is a natural fit for the off-site resource close reason any more than asking about the existence of a function within a specific library is - and if it *is* off-topic, then basically any "how do I do X with API Y?" question is off-topic, including several of the highest-upvoted coinbase-api questions. That seems wrong to me - though as usual with this close reason, I seem to be the lone dissenter.

Comment: I agree with @MarkAmery. This is because if worded differently but asking exactly the same question most of us would agree that it is not off topic. This question basically asks "How can I test the Coinbase API"?

Comment: It seems that the question might have been just poorly worded, and OP chose to become belligerent instead of clarifying what they were asking. From what I can ascertain, the Coinbase Sandbox is a service that provides an API for testing bitcoin operations. So if OP had asked their question as "Does the Coinbase Sandbox API have an endpoint for testing the creation of wallets, sending, receiving and login? If so, what is it?" I think that would have been a valid question.

Comment: @MarkAmery: A lot of _"How do I do <X> in library <Y>"_ questions are still off-topic / too broad, though. Just dumping a requirement in a SO question doesn't cut it, and that was what the question was. I agree that there are exceptions, but questions like that have to be very well written to be worth keeping.

Comment: @Cerbrus When has "How do I read a file in node.js" or "How to cancel a deferred function in jQuery" or "How to define related tables in Mongoose" ever been off topic? "How do I do <x> in library <y>" is not and has never been off topic. What's off topic is "Is there a library in language <x> that does <y>"

Comment: @slebetman: If all the question contains is _"How do I read a file in node.js?"_, then there is an extreme lack of effort on the asker's side. We don't want requirement dumps. We want researched questions. That's why those questions are more often than not __too broad__ (The reason you overlooked from my comment)

Comment: @Cerbrus Also, Coinbase is not a library. It is a technology. You are asking SO to ban questions in the form "How to test my MySQL database?" or "How to debug HTML"

Comment: Those are actually too broad... Unless they include a clear problem statement and code to reproduce an issue. But these are all examples that are different from the case this question is about. I don't really see their relevance here.

Comment: @Cerbrus It is however extremely on topic back in 2009 when node.js was just introduced. Part of the reason it is gooleable now is exactly because someone answered it on SO. Coinbase is just recently introduced so such questions would be extremely on topic now

Comment: @slebetman: But still ___too broad___. _How do I do <X> with <Y>_ is too broad. _How do I do <X> with <Y>, I tried <Z>_ isn't too broad.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Broadness does not matter as broad questions are not off topic

Comment: @slebetman: _"Too broad"_ is still a close reason. The end result is the same. Such questions should be closed, as they are of no value to the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Note that SO defines too broad as "Questions about general computing hardware and software" and "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration"

Comment: @slebetman: _"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."_ That's the **too broad** close vote. What you quote are the first two __off topic__ close reasons. That's completely different. Before we continue this discussion, please have another look at the close-vote popup so you're up to speed about the difference between **too broad** and **off-topic**.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"How do I do <X> with <Y> is too broad. How do I do <X> with <Y>, I tried <Z> isn't too broad."* - this is probably a separate argument to the tool recommendation one, but I strongly disagree with this too; *How do I do <X> with <Y>, I tried <Z>* is much *more* likely to be too broad since it's still asking the same question but *also* implicitly throwing in a tangentially related question of *plz debug Z*; it's thereby strictly broadening the set of acceptable answers and increasing the required length of a thorough answer that covers everything in the question.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I disagree that those questions are more broad. Yes, they usually are _"Please debug Z"_, but in my experience, those questions are at least clear and answerable.

Comment: It may be worth noting that searching in Google for the title of the question under scrutiny gives the answer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton these days, there are almost no questions that can't be answered with a quick google search, or by breaking it down into smaller parts. That's why my account only answers - I have no questions.

Comment: @Solver Me neither*, but when putting the actual question title into Google gives the answer, you have to wonder how much effort the poster put into their research. * Maybe one day I'll find out something that deserves a self-answered question.